# Do I really need libgcc?

Tags: c, macos, cocoa, gcc

I've been using GCC 4.6.2 on Mac OS X 10.6. I use the `-static-libgcc` option when I compile, otherwise my binaries look for `libgcc` on the system and I'm not sure anything over GCC 4.2 is supported on OS X. This works fine, but why do I even need `libgcc`? I read up on it and the GNU docs say it contains "arithmetic operations that the target processor cannot perform directly." How do I know what these operations are? And why are they so complex that I need to include this library? Why can't GCC just optimize the code directly instead of having to resort to these library functions? I'm a little confused. Any insight into this would be appreciated!

Comment: Possible same on Unix: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1812/what-does-libgcc-s-so-contain

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Yes, you do need it .... probably. If you don't need it then statically linking it is harmless. You can tell if you need it by using the `-t` link trace option (I think).

There are various things that you cant do in one instruction (typically things like 64-bit operations on 32-bit architectures). These things can be done, but if they use a non-trivial number of instructions then it's more space-efficient to have them all in one place.

When you disable optimization using `-O0` (that's actually the default anyway) then GCC pretty much always uses the libgcc routines.

When you enable *speed* optimization then GCC may choose to insert the instruction sequence directly into the code (if it knows how). You may find that it ends up using none of the libgcc versions - it will certainly use fewer libgcc calls.

When you enable *size* optimizations then GCC may prefer the function call, or may not - it depends on what the GCC developers think is the best speed/size trade-off in each case. Note that even when you tell it to optimize for speed, the compiler may judge that *some* functions are unlikely to be used, and optimize those for size - even more so if you use PGO.

Basically, you can think of it in the same way as `memcpy` or the math-library functions: the compiler will inline functions it judges to be beneficial, and call library functions otherwise. The compiler can "inline" standard functions and libgcc function without looking at the library definition, of course - it just "knows" what they do.

Whether to use static or dynamic libgcc is an interesting trade-off. On the one hand, a dynamic (shared) library will use less memory across your whole system, and is more likely to be cached, etc. On the other hand, a static libgcc has a lower call overhead.

The most important thing though is compatibility. Obviously the libgcc library has to be present for your program to run, but it also has to be a compatible *version*. You're ok on a Linux distro with a stable GCC version, but otherwise static linking is safer.

I hope that answers your questions.

Comment: Thanks, are there any issue could be found on Internet about not including libgcc, libgcc_s in executable?