# When does cmake not generate "-L" flag for link_directories?

Tags: android, cmake, cross-compiling

Here is a simplified CMakeLists.txt that I am using to cross-compile a shared library for Android.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(MyTest)
link_directories($ENV{ANDROID_PREBUILT}/gcc/linux-x86/arm/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.9)
add_library(MyTest SHARED MyTest.cpp)
```

When building, the error I get is:

```
xxx/gcc/linux-x86/arm/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-ld:   
error: cannot find -lgcc
```

I see that the link directory I specified does have libgcc.a file.

Running make in verbose mode shows the following link command:

```
xxx/clang/host/linux-x86/clang-2690385/bin/clang++
  --target=arm-linux-androideabi
  --sysroot=xxx/ndk/current/platforms/android-23/arch-arm/usr
  -fPIC -O3 -DNDEBUG  -shared -Wl,-soname,libMyTest.so -o libMyTest.so
  CMakeFiles/MyTest.dir/MyTest.cpp.o
```

It appears `-L` flag is not getting generated by cmake.

If I directly run the above command with `-L` flag, linking goes through fine and the shared library does get created.

Can someone please tell me what is it that I am missing?

Update:

I have tried exporting `LIBRARY_PATH` as well as `LDFLAGS` but both are being ignored.

Comment: As far as I understand, CMake treats link directories added with `link_directories` or `target_link_directories` as hints for **direct linking** with libraries (`target_link_libraries`). Linking with proper `gcc` is responsibility of the toolchain/platform file, not of the  `CMakeLists.txt`.

Comment: Thank you for your help. The link_directories is actually defined in toolchain file and is being used with -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE.

Comment: @Peter the export variable is LD_LIBRARY_PATH. Aside from that, when you manually executed clang, can you see the linker invocation by adding a `-v` option? Moreover, can you try the original compilation with the `-nostdlib` flag, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51173869/3048763)  related post. Lastly, the `-lgcc` will try to find libgcc.so, is that shared library in the required dir along with its static version (i.e., libgcc.a)?